# Why do I get "101: Network is unreachable" when trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: upgrade, updates, partial-upgrade

I am facing these errors while I am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04:

```
E: Failed to fetch 
http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/archive/pool/main/x/xdg-desktop- portal-gtk/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk_1.6.0-1_amd64.deb  
Cannot initiate the connection to ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au:80 (2401:fc00:0:201::4). - 
connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

Comment: Looks like a dns problem.  Try on phone or other computer to see if you can get to that site.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Activities, open Software & Updates.  Go to the Ubuntu Software tab, dropdown 'Download from:', and choose Main Server.  Or, choose 'Other', and run 'Select Best Server'.  Then run your upgrade commands.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it worked yesterday with no changes, looks like some intermittent connectivity issues.
But my wallpaper is not changed. It still shows the old wallpaper and not that of fosca. Any inputs on this please.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question about the wallpaper issue.